# Bind and display Collection(Edm.String)

Tags: odata, sapui5

I'm wondering how to bind Complex type - Collection(Edm.String- into List. Example:

Service (odata v4) https://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW.

Entity Type :Person has property :

```
<Property Name="Emails" Type="Collection(Edm.String)"/>
```

I setup something like (XML view)

```
<List  id="list0" items="{Emails}">
        <items>
            <StandardListItem title="{}"  id="item1"/>
        </items>
    </List>
```

Number of items is ok but the content of the title is not displayed . What should I put there ?
[Screen output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8jx2.jpg)
[oData response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fGWF.jpg)